# How can I get branch of a networkx graph as a list from pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
From    To
0   Node1   Node2
1   Node1   Node3
2   Node2   Node4
3   Node2   Node5
4   Node3   Node6
5   Node3   Node7
6   Node4   Node8
7   Node5   Node9
8   Node6   Node10
9   Node7   Node11
```

`df.to_dict()` is:

```
{'From': {0: 'Node1',
  1: 'Node1',
  2: 'Node2',
  3: 'Node2',
  4: 'Node3',
  5: 'Node3',
  6: 'Node4',
  7: 'Node5',
  8: 'Node6',
  9: 'Node7'},
 'To': {0: 'Node2',
  1: 'Node3',
  2: 'Node4',
  3: 'Node5',
  4: 'Node6',
  5: 'Node7',
  6: 'Node8',
  7: 'Node9',
  8: 'Node10',
  9: 'Node11'}}
```

I have plotted this pandas dataframe as a network graph using networkx package which looks as follows:
[image]

I want to get the list of unique scenarios/branches from this network graph.
There are four branches here starting from Node1.

```
Node1-Node2-Node4-Node8
Node1-Node2-Node5-Node9
Node1-Node3-Node6-Node10
Node1-Node3-Node7-Node11
```

How can I get the list of the branches above from the given pandas dataframe in Python?

Comment: I don't know of any methods within Pandas that will do what you want.  Sounds to mean like you need to utilize a Depth First Search Algorithim to identify all paths in Graph from a starting Node.  Plenty of article on web regarding this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `Recursive Function` and save path and print path:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'From':['Node1','Node1', 'Node2', 'Node2', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node4', 'Node5', 'Node6', 'Node7'],
          'TO'  :['Node2','Node3', 'Node4', 'Node5', 'Node6', 'Node7', 'Node8', 'Node9', 'Node10', 'Node11']
        })

def prntPath(lst, node, df, lst_vst):
    for val in df.values:
        if val[0] == node:
            lst.append(val[1])
            prntPath(lst, val[1], df, lst_vst)
    
    if not lst[-1] in lst_vst:
        print('-'.join(lst))
    for l in lst: lst_vst.add(l)
    lst.pop()
    return
    
lst_vst = set()
prntPath(['Node1'],'Node1', df, lst_vst)
```

Output:

```
Node1-Node2-Node4-Node8
Node1-Node2-Node5-Node9
Node1-Node3-Node6-Node10
Node1-Node3-Node7-Node11
```

**You can check and use for other graph like below:**

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain
from networkx.drawing.nx_pydot import graphviz_layout

def prntPath(lst, node, df, lst_vst):
    for val in df.values:
        if val[0] == node:
            lst.append(val[1])
            prntPath(lst, val[1], df, lst_vst)
    if not lst[-1] in lst_vst: print('-'.join(lst))
    for l in lst: lst_vst.add(l)
    lst.pop()
    return

df = pd.DataFrame({
          'From':['Node1','Node1', 'Node2', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node5', 'Node7'],
          'TO'  :['Node2','Node3', 'Node5', 'Node6', 'Node7', 'Node9', 'Node11']
        })

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(set(chain.from_iterable(df.values)))
for edg in df.values:
    g.add_edge(*edg)
pos = graphviz_layout(g, prog="dot")
nx.draw(g, pos,with_labels=True, node_shape='s')
plt.draw()
plt.show() 

lst_vst = set()
prntPath(['Node1'],'Node1', df, lst_vst)
```

Output:

[image]

```
Node1-Node2-Node5-Node9
Node1-Node3-Node6
Node1-Node3-Node7-Node11
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am getting NameError: name "fun" is not defined. Could you possibly explain what this function is about? Could you possibly add more comments for comprehension purpose?

Comment: @hbstha123 edited answer, this function in iterate like DFS, you need know about dfs and end of for we print path, read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search)

Comment: Thank you! I have marked it as correct as I get the required list. I get the results as NoneType. Is it also possible to get results in the form of dataframe?

Comment: @hbstha123 where is result that you got NoneType, I don't use `result` in answer

Comment: When I do: type(getScenarios(['Node1'],'Node1', df, lst_vst)). I get NoneType. I was wondering if it's possible to get the list in dataframe in nodes A, B, C and D.

Comment: like this : A = Node1-Node2-Node4-Node8 , B = Node1-Node2-Node4-Node9 , ...?

Comment: I meant: A = Node1, Node1, Node1, Node1. B = Node2, Node2, Node3,Node3,  C =  Node4, Node5, Node6, Node7 and D = Node8, Node9, Node10, Node11 from the first example in the top.

Comment: @hbstha123 this is another question and this BFS, please post another question, here if I answer you I will get downvote from other users because this is not answer of your question

Comment: @hbstha123 I can answer you, but I now need to go, I answer you until ten hour, If this late you can post another question

Comment: I will post a new question and share the link to you here.

Comment: It's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69603238/how-can-i-get-branch-of-a-networkx-graph-from-pandas-dataframe-in-python-in-the

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach to solve this using the networkx package.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from((r.From, r.To) for r in df.itertuples())

roots = [n for (n, d) in G.in_degree if d == 0]
print(roots)

leafs = [n for (n, d) in G.out_degree if d == 0]
print(leafs)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(nx.algorithms.all_simple_paths(G, roots[0], leafs))

for index in df1:
    print (df1.loc[index].to_list())
```

A directed graph is created and the edges are added to it from `df`. Node 1 is the only node in G, where the in_degree is equal to 0, i.e. it is the root of the entire graph. Therefore, `roots` is equal to Node 0.

`leafs` imply the nodes at the directed graph at which out_degree is equal to 0. i.e., ["Node8", "Node9", "Node10", "Node11"].

`nx.algorithms.all_simple_paths(G, roots[0], leafs)` provide all the paths starting from Node 1 and ending at each of the nodes in leafs.

Each row of the dataframe `df1` is printed as a list using the for-loop statement.

Answer (score 2):

I think @I'mahdi's first snippet of code assumes that a child node will not have more than one parent node, i.e., the graph is a binary tree. When the graph is not a binary tree, the code can be modified as:

```
import pandas as pd

def prntPath(lst, node, df, lst_vst):
    for val in df.values:
        if val[0] == node:
            lst.append(val[1])
            # recursely find child node first until no child nodes are found
            prntPath(lst, val[1], df, lst_vst)
            
            # recursion is over
    
    # when no child nodes are found
    if len(lst)>=2:
        if (not lst[-1] in lst_vst) or (not lst[-2] in lst_vst):
            print('-'.join(lst))
    for l in lst:
        lst_vst.add(l)
    lst.pop()

# Two links are added to the graph: 1) from node 4 to node 9. 2) from node 1 to node 11.
 
df = pd.DataFrame({
          'From':['Node1','Node1', 'Node2', 'Node2', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node4', 'Node4','Node5', 'Node6', 'Node7','Node1'],
          'TO'  :['Node2','Node3', 'Node4', 'Node5', 'Node6', 'Node7', 'Node8', 'Node9','Node9', 'Node10', 'Node11','Node12']
        })
lst_vst = set()
prntPath(['Node1'],'Node1', df, lst_vst)
```

The results are:

```
Node1-Node2-Node4-Node8
Node1-Node2-Node4-Node9
Node1-Node2-Node5-Node9
Node1-Node3-Node6-Node10
Node1-Node3-Node7-Node11
Node1-Node12
```