# How can I get branch of a networkx graph from pandas dataframe in Python in the form of a new pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, function

I have a pandas dataframe `df` which looks as follows:

```
From    To
0   Node1   Node2
1   Node1   Node3
2   Node2   Node4
3   Node2   Node5
4   Node3   Node6
5   Node3   Node7
6   Node4   Node8
7   Node5   Node9
8   Node6   Node10
9   Node7   Node11
```

`df.to_dict()` is:

```
{'From': {0: 'Node1',
  1: 'Node1',
  2: 'Node2',
  3: 'Node2',
  4: 'Node3',
  5: 'Node3',
  6: 'Node4',
  7: 'Node5',
  8: 'Node6',
  9: 'Node7'},
 'To': {0: 'Node2',
  1: 'Node3',
  2: 'Node4',
  3: 'Node5',
  4: 'Node6',
  5: 'Node7',
  6: 'Node8',
  7: 'Node9',
  8: 'Node10',
  9: 'Node11'}}
```

I have plotted this pandas dataframe as a network graph using networkx package which looks as follows:
[image]

I want to get the unique scenarios/branches from this network graph in the form of a new pandas dataframe as follows:

```
  A B   C   D
0   Node1   Node2   Node4   Node8
1   Node1   Node2   Node5   Node9
2   Node1   Node3   Node6   Node10
3   Node1   Node3   Node7   Node11
```

How is it possible to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate graph like `DFS` then save path on each iterate and return path and convert to `DataFrame` like below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
          'From':['Node1','Node1', 'Node2', 'Node2', 'Node3', 'Node3', 'Node4', 'Node5', 'Node6', 'Node7'],
          'TO'  :['Node2','Node3', 'Node4', 'Node5', 'Node6', 'Node7', 'Node8', 'Node9', 'Node10', 'Node11']
        })

fnl_result = []
def svPath(path, node, df, lst_vst, fnl_result):
    for val in df.values:
        if val[0] == node:
            path.append(val[1])
            svPath(path, val[1], df, lst_vst, fnl_result)
    
    if not path[-1] in lst_vst:
        fnl_result.append([p for p in path])
    for p in path: lst_vst.add(p)
    path.pop()
    return
    
lst_vst = set()
svPath(['Node1'],'Node1', df, lst_vst, fnl_result)
dfOut = pd.DataFrame(fnl_result, columns=['A','B','C','D'])
```

Output:

```
>>> dfOut
        A       B       C       D
0   Node1   Node2   Node4   Node8
1   Node1   Node2   Node5   Node9
2   Node1   Node3   Node6   Node10
3   Node1   Node3   Node7   Node11
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already using networkx, why not ask it to get the paths for you:

```
import networkx as nx

# create a digraph from your edges
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist( df, 'From', 'To', create_using=nx.DiGraph())
root_node = 'Node1'
leaf_nodes = df.To[~(df.To.isin(df.From))]

# get all paths from leaf_nodes back to root_node
paths = []
for node in leaf_nodes:
    paths.append( nx.shortest_path(G, root_node, node) )
result = pd.DataFrame(paths)
```

result:

```
       0      1      2       3
0  Node1  Node2  Node4   Node8
1  Node1  Node2  Node5   Node9
2  Node1  Node3  Node6  Node10
3  Node1  Node3  Node7  Node11
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to solve this using the networkx package.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edges_from((r.From, r.To) for r in df.itertuples())
roots = [n for (n, d) in G.in_degree if d == 0]
print(roots)
leafs = [n for (n, d) in G.out_degree if d == 0]
print(leafs)
pd.DataFrame(
    nx.algorithms.all_simple_paths(G, roots[0], leafs)
)
```

A directed graph is created and the edges are added to it from `df`. Node 1 is the only node in G, where the in_degree is equal to 0, i.e. it is the root of the entire graph. Therefore, `roots` is equal to Node 0.

`leafs` imply the nodes at the directed graph at which out_degree is equal to 0. i.e., ["Node8", "Node9", "Node10", "Node11"].

`nx.algorithms.all_simple_paths(G, roots[0], leafs)` provide the list of all the paths starting from Node 1 and ending at each of the nodes in leafs.